# Wpf ItemSource Doesn't Update Visual Control in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control with itemsSource binding:

```
    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        Results.Clear();
        foreach (var check in newValue)
        {
            Results.Add(check as Check);
        }
    }

    protected ObservableCollection<Check> results = new ObservableCollection<Check>();

    public ObservableCollection<Check> Results
    {
        get { return results; }
        set { results = value; }
    }
```

Implemented in the main view:

```
<control:ResultCtrl x:Name="resultCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"></control:ResultCtrl>
```

Check class:

```
    public class Check : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected string checkStateString;

    public string CheckStateString
    {
        get { return checkStateString; }
        set
        {
            if (value != checkStateString)
            {
                checkStateString = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CheckStateString"));
            }
        }
    }
```

I call a class who calculate checks in the Main View show method:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
            delegate
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<ResultCtrl>(AddIn.Services.Results.Comprobaciones), resultCtrl);
            }
            ));
            t.Start();
```

In AddIn.Services.Results.Comprobaciones I do:

```
resultCtrl.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Check>(AddIn.Document.Results);
```

for every check. Every time I do that I see how ItemsSource change, but Visual only update when the AddIn.Services.Results.Comprobaciones end. I tried to do UpdateLayout() and Items.Refresh() but nothing work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(/* ...  */);
t.Start();
```

creates a thread, that is completely useless, because everything it does is a blocking call to UI thread's `Dispatcher`. In other words, 99.999...% of time it runs on UI thread. You could easily write this:

```
AddIn.Services.Results.Comprobaciones();
```

with the same result.

You have to rewrite your code for having any benefits from multi-threading. I have no idea, how does your `Comprobaciones` method look like, but, obviously, you should call `Dispatcher.Invoke` only when you need to update something in UI.

Also note, that in most cases you shouldn't create `Thread` instances directly. Consider using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead (possibly, via `async`/`await`, if you're targeting .NET 4.5).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. AddIn.Services.Results.Comprobaciones(); take some time so thats why I need in other thread. I want to have the View visible and being filled for AddIn.Services.Results.Comprobaciones();.

Comment: So, run `Comprobaciones` in background thread. But don't run it in `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Possibly, it will be enoungh to wrap this line `resultCtrl.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Check>(AddIn.Document.Results);` in `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Again, I don't know anything about the content of `Comprobaciones`. Maybe, there is another code, which should be run on UI thread.

Comment: Comprobaciones looks like:                         if (establishmentsChecks())
                        {
                            resultCtrl.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Check>(AddIn.Document.Results);
                            if (roomsChecks())
                            {
                                resultCtrl.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Check>(AddIn.Document.Results); I want to update visual every time I do resultCtrl.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Check>(AddIn.Document.Results); but only updated when method finish